# How to get hive table comment through JDBC

Tags: jdbc, hive

Assume that a table is created like following in **Hive**:

```
create table test1
(
    field_name int 
)comment='TestTableComment';
```

Now I'd like to get the comment for the table (TestTableComment) through JDBC in Java, how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `DatabaseMetaData.getTables()`?

[Reference](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000052805?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=forum&utm_campaign=support&utm_term=ber&utm_content=datadirect)